# One less thing to worry about

Tags: expressions, word-order, comparatives

I am not a native English speaker but I usually feel comfortable speaking or writing in English. I also have a linguistic background. But this morning I finished a task, wiped it from my whiteboard, and said to myself "That's one thing less to worry about". This raised two questions in my brain that was still running on high-energy consumption:

- Is it "one thing less" or "one less thing"?  My non-native gut tells me both are OK but is there a difference in meaning?
- Why is it "less"? "A thing" is countable; there can be two things. On my to-do list, I have removed one item and still have 5 items left. So now there are fewer items on my list, not less. So why does "one less thing" feel so much more natural than "one fewer thing"?

Now off for coffee.

Comment: Syntactically, ***less*** can come before or after the noun *(**thing**)* that it modifies. But per [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one+thing+less+to+worry%2Cone+less+thing+to+worry&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), most people still put the adjective *before* the noun, reflecting the "default" position of adjectives in English. But [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one+thing+less+to+worry%2Cone+less+thing+to+worry&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) shows higher "non-standard" BrE use.

Comment: ...obviously "one less thing" feels so much more natural than "one fewer thing" *because that's the idiomatic standard* (so it's what we're used to hearing). Besides which, there can't be many people left who still care about the pedantic Victorian distinction between ***less*** and ***fewer*** - the latter of which continues to decline overall, anyway.

Comment: @FF The English have an aversion to fewerers.

Comment: My dudes, __not a duplicate__, or rather the main question is about 'thing less' vs 'less thing'. When in doubt, __don't close__ (there's no doubt here, the main question is new).

Comment: Confusion here is that the named duplicate does cover part of the question. The issue with calling the action "closing" is that it comes off as "deleting". Duplicates expand the search net, but consolidate the answers in a single place . Ideally. Practically, there is leakage.

Comment: @Mitch There should be one fewer question in a legitimate 'question'. And reasonable research for 'one less thing' vs 'one thing less' would include ngrams and raw Google data.

Comment: Susanta Sahoo, author of 'Common English Errors', [addresses](https://commonenglisherrors.com/one-less-thing-vs-one-fewer-thing-one-correct/) both questions (admittedly .without authoritative references). The second question is answered: << "One Less Thing" vs "One Thing Less" ... If you’re wondering if you should use “one less thing” or “one thing less”, rest assured: both are correct. However, “one less thing” is more common than “one thing less”.

[Recapping]:
• I now have one less thing to worry about. (Right)
• I now have one thing less to worry about. (Acceptable) >> [sl. adjusted]

Comment: @Lawrence Thanks, fixed!

Answer (score 2):

I will venture an answer here which isn't based on frequency. No prescriptive grammar here: both forms are idiomatic.

When we take care of something, we can think to ourselves:

> That is one thing less to worry about.
>
> That is one less thing to worry about.

The word "that" doesn't refer to the task but to the set of things to worry about now that the task has been completed. One thing has been removed from the set of things to worry about. That set of tasks is **less** by one task; the set contains *one thing less* or *one less thing*. When the job is done, you wipe your hands off against each other, and say "*That's that!*"

There is greater emphasis on **less** in "one thing less" and greater emphasis on **one** in "one less thing".  **one thing less** emphasizes the reduction of worry, and **one less thing** emphasizes the degree to which the worry has been reduced.

Compare "one more day" and "one day more".

> Cratchit: Give them *one* more day to pay the rent.
>
> Scrooge: No, I won't give them one day *more*.

Cratchit is beseeching Scrooge, emphasizing that it is only one additional day of grace, and Scrooge in his reply emphasizes that the grace has been extended as much as it will be.